# jQuery validation of dropdownlist on Kendo window

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm having a problem with using jQuery validation to validate Kendo widgets (dropdownlist in particular) that are on a modal KendoWindow which is populated with a form retrieved using AJAX. Validation works beautifully for everything except the Kendo widgets that use hidden fields (dropdownlist, textarea, etc) I've seen many posts ([here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/integration/integration/kendo-widgets-and-jquery-validator.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/01/14/making-the-kendo-ui-editor-work-with-jquery-validations/), for example) that describe and solve very similar problems, but these approaches do not seem to work on a modal KendoWindow. The solution should be something like this:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ""});
```

but it does not work in my case. Here's my code from my partial view which loads the modal window via ajax:

```
    @model ProductManagement.Models.BaseModel

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function () {
            $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: "" });
        });
    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)...
```

Is there a trick for doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I really spent a lot of time on this, but I did get it working. The answer, of course, is extremely simple. Here are the takeaways:

To configure a Kendo UI popup window to use jQuery validation (MVC 4):

1. I got this working using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1. Not sure how to do this using version >1.9.
2. In _Layout.cshtml, add the following to the document ready function:
   $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: "" }); **EDIT: This is incorrect. Not needed for version 1.8.1.**
3. On the partial view that contains the popup form, reference jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
4. On the form, all fields must have correct naming. For example, I'm using a view model which causes field names to look like "VM_ProductInfo.Product_ID", "VM_ProductInfo.Product_Name", etc. If any field is named inconsistently, for example just "Product_Description" (without the "VM_ProductInfo." prefix), validation only partially works correctly and the form submits despite errors.
5. On the form, include ValidationMessageFor for any hidden fields. For example, if I were to hide the Product_ID field, I would still need to include validation, like this:

   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product_ID)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_ID)

Looking back, numbers 4 and 5 above are what caused me the most grief. I would have saved many hours of head banging if I had known to check for these.

This was a trial-and-error solution. Please reply if you know a better way.

Side note: The Kendo documentation says that specifying a Name for the Dropdownlist widget is [mandatory](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/dropdownlist/overview/%20mandatory). It ain't, at least as far as I can tell. By leaving off the .Name, the form builds with naming that's consistent with the rest of the form.